# Having non-English Text in the addon code of blender

Tags: python, add-on, text-editor

I wanna have Persian text in the addon code of blender.For example I want to use this code: `layout.label(text="سلام")`.
What should I've done?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable international fonts in user preferences. Bottom right corner.
[image]